# How to find out if a numeric(18,2) contains decimal places?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to run a Case statement where given the table numeric(18,2) field contains decimal places, it will print 'a' otherwise it will print 'b'

any idea?

Comment: You mean if it contains anything other than `.00`? Surely by definition all values will contain a decimal place.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about:

```
select case
    when cast(mycol as int) = mycol then 'b' 
    else 'a'
end
```